# javascript how to simulate function global scope for Json statement?

Tags: javascript

javascript how to simulate function global scope for Json statement?

```
   var testJson=
    {
        a1: 1,
        a2: this.a1+1
    }
```

and the result should be:

```
var testJson=
{
    a1: 1,
    a2: 2
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `var testJson= { a1: 1 }; testJson.a2 = testJson.a1 + 1;`?  What you want can only be done through a function call, but not object notation, at least not in a way you're looking to do...unless I'm completely misunderstanding.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: @Nick Craver : You are right,I just want to wirte less code.
the right way is:
 var testJson=
    {
        a1: 1,
        a2: testJson.a1+1
    }

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to either define a variable outside `testJson`, or use a function as the value of `a2`, like this:

```
var testJson = {
  a1: 1,
  a2: function () {
    return this.a1 + 1;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not support code execution. The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) is simply a means for serializing and unserializing information for transport. There should be no executable content in a JSON string.

JSON parsers should fail when they encounter a non-literal value in a JSON string.

The only exception to this rule is with JSON-P, which wraps a JSON string in a function call in order to bypass cross-domain mechanisms.

Comment: Well, that's not really JSON, it's just Javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible easily. It may be possible, but it would probably involve creating a function from an object and back again. This would be a lot easier:

```
var testJson=
{
    a1: 1,
    a2: function(){return this.a1+1}
}
```

which you could evaluate using

```
testJson.a2();
```

this should work out of the box